# Reject from google play store

Tags: android, android-intent, android-permissions

I am tried to upload my apps in google play store. I add my gradle permission list and reject reason. How can Solve it?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
```

**Rejected cause.**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because google has changed the policy on

> SMS/Call Log permissions

If you want to use these permissions, your app should have the capability to act as a default app for doing that task. eg, If you want to read or send sms from users mobile via your app then your app should be the default app for reading and sending sms in users phone, same scenario goes for call permissions. In your manifest your have declared these permissions.

> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"
>
> uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"

Read more info on xda portal:

Link 1: [google-play-developer-policy-call-log-sms](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-play-developer-policy-call-log-sms/)

Link 2: [Update: Tasker Gets Approved](https://www.xda-developers.com/google-restriction-sms-call-log-permissions/)

If you are planning to read OTP for verification then google has made new SMS retriever API. [docs](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/)

Comment: If I remove this `uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"`.
 That time is it needed to fill up google doc form.

Comment: not needed, just remove the above mentioned permissions.

Comment: You should remove only SEND_SMS permission, and create a new release in production track, try doing a full roll out